# Database SQL - Query to find top 5 values and total generated by each value

Tags: sql, database

I need an SQL query to list the top 5 most frequently rented DVD's, sorted in descending
order. For each record i need to show: DVD title, the rented frequency and the
total rent income generated by each DVD title.

My table:
DVD

My attributes:
DVD-Title,
DVD-sales (Number of sales of the single DVD title in that record),
DVD-Total (Total of sales (£) of the single DVD title in that record

I have got this myself:

```
SELECT DVD-title, DVD-sales
FROM DVD
WHERE 
(
DVD-sales IN 
(
SELECT TOP (5) DVD-sales
FROM table as DVD       
GROUP BY DVD-sales     
ORDER BY DVD-sales DESC
)
)
```

(is "table as" a key word? or should i put my table name there?)

Not sure if the above code is right or not, and i dont know how to do the total rent income generated for each DVD title

Please include a SQL code solution in you answers, thank you!

Comment: Could you show what you have done to solve the problem yourself? Also, is this homework?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I do not see how this could be homework. Not from a `KnowledgeWizard`.

Comment: Its not home work, im just trying to learn SQL myself from looking online. Im using SQL server for a bases of my database, but slightly changing the code to fit the format of the guide i was following, but SQL server code should be fine.

Comment: Do you have a single row for each DVD title, or could the same title occur on a number of different rows?

Comment: @Alan the same title could occur a number of times (As if it were rented by many different people at different times) Is this what you meant?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. That invalidates the answer I gave below, as it assumes a single row per title. I'll update it.

Comment: @Alan Thank you for your answer. Could i just ask as i am not very experienced with sql and am not sure...What are "TotalQuantity" and "TotalValue"? Are they new attributes i require in my database? Or something else? and is the "A" after the last bracket supposed to be there?

Comment: I answered below the answer... TotalQuantity/Value aren't new attributes, they are names I used in the example. 'SUM (DVD-Sales) AS TotalQuantity' simply means add together all of the DVD-Sales values, and call the result 'TotalQuantity'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the table has a single row per title, it would be as simple as:

```
SELECT TOP 5 "DVD-Title", "DVD-Sales", "DVD-Total"
FROM DVD
ORDER BY "DVD-Sales" DESC
```

However, assuming the same title can occur multiple times, a query such as the following should work:

```
SELECT TOP 5 "DVD-Title", TotalQuantity, TotalValue
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        DVD-Title,
        SUM("DVD-Sales") AS TotalQuantity,
        SUM("DVD-Total") AS TotalValue
    FROM DVD
    GROUP BY "DVD-Title"
) A
ORDER BY TotalQuantity DESC
```

What this query is doing is first summarising your data so that it has a single row per title, and then sorting this resulting data by the total quantity in descending order, and returning the first 5 results.

Comment: sounds to me like this is exactly what ive been trying to figure out, thank you very much! Just one thing, is the "A" after the last bracket supposed to be there?

Comment: Yes, the 'A' is supposed to be there - it gives a name to the results of the subquery. The TotalQuantity and TotalValue are names I gave to the summed values (sorry, I should probably have picked names that more closely resembled your names).

Comment: It might be clearer to you if you run the subquery on it's own - everything from "SELECT DVD-Title" through to "GROUP BY DVD-Title". You'll see the results, which we're then calling 'A' and treating them as if they are a table we can select from.

Comment: Thank you Alan, you help a lot :)